# javascript/sqlite noob -declaration of variables

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to learn sqlite ,after some time of learning JS.  I've recently found a short tutorial about how to create a to do list with sqlite and JS . here is some of the code:

```
var html5rocks = {};
html5rocks.webdb = {};
html5rocks.webdb.db = null;

html5rocks.webdb.open = function() {
  var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
  html5rocks.webdb.db = openDatabase("Todo", "1.0", "Todo manager", dbSize);
}

html5rocks.webdb.createTable = function() {
  var db = html5rocks.webdb.db;
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME)", []);
  });
}
```

What I don't understand is why the declaration of  `html5rocks.webdb = {};` and `html5rocks.webdb.db = null;'` was written like that. How can you assign `webdb` and `webdb.db` in that way before you declare them as  variables inside `'html5rocks{}?`

I've never seen this way to declare variables. 
Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{} is an object.

[] is an array.

So,

```
var html5rocks = {};  // object html5rocks is made, and is still empty
html5rocks.webdb = {};  // now html5rocks has a property: Webdb.  Webdb itself is an object.
html5rocks.webdb.db = null; // db, set to null, is added to Webdb (itself a property of html5rocks )
```

The nice thing about javascript: you don't need classes, you just do it.  You make a new property, you can instantly use it.

OOP languages usually need multiple lines of code.  In javascript: existingObject.newProperty = 'new value';